# JavaScript Call addEventListener from another addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger first event listener, when second was clicked. Currently I'm trying to call first event listener with specified index in second:

```
allGallerySlides.forEach((val, i) function(){
   val.addEventListener('click', function(){
       //some stuff to do
   });
});

allSlideInfos.forEach((val, i) function(){
   val.addEventListener('click', function(){
       //trigger first addEventListener here
       allGallerySlides[i].click();
   });
});
```

How to do that?

Comment: Just create a function that is called from both, much better than trying to trigger events for their side effects, you never know who else may be listening to clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an event like it was an event on another element using [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

```js
document.links[0].addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.innerText, 'was clicked');
});

document.links[1].addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.innerText, 'was clicked');
  let event = new Event('click');
  document.links[0].dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<p><a href="1">Event 1</a></p>
<p><a href="2">Event 2</a></p>
```